# pentaho ETL Tool data migration

Tags: pentaho

I am migrating the data through pentaho. there is a problem occur when the number of rows is more than 4 lankhs.transaction fail in b/w the transaction.how can we migrate the large data by pentaho ETL Tool.

Comment: can you share the error log or the specific error which you are geting while loading the data ?? 4 lac is a small volume of data.. ideally it shouldnt throw error in pdi !!

Comment: "transaction fail in b/w the transaction." - what does this sentence mean? And what are "lankhs"?

Answer (score 0):

As a basic debugging, do the following

If your output is a text file or Excel file, make sure that you check the size of string/text columns. As defaut the 'text ouput step' will take the maximum string length and when you start writing, it can throw up heap errors. So reduce the size and re-run the ktr files.

If the output is a table ouput step, then again check for columns with datatypes and maximum column size defined in your output table.

Kindly share the error logs if you think there is something else running around. :)